# Omitting Wikipedia maintenance categories from sql query

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, wikipedia, categories

I am retrieving a list of categories for a given page_title, but the results include categories such as:

"All_articles_to_be_split"
"Articles_with_unsourced_statements_from_July_2008"
"All_articles_with_specifically-marked_weasel-worded_phrases"
...etc...I wish to omit these types of categories that are for maintenance.

Here is an example sql call I am making:

```
SELECT categorylinks.cl_to 
  FROM categorylinks 
  JOIN page ON categorylinks.cl_from = page.page_id 
           AND page.page_namespace = 0 
           AND page.page_title = "Ice_hockey";
```

What am I missing in my query to omit the maintenance categories?  Or will I have to manually parse these out of my results? Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a connected problem. Can you help me at finding where is used this query in the PHP code of mediawiki?

Comment: (This is the question I've just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807663/showing-only-user-created-category-not-maintenance-categories)

Comment: When I asked this question 11 years ago, I wasn't working with mediawiki PHP code. I had to write my own application and was making raw SQL queries to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it manually like this:

```
SELECT categorylinks.cl_to 
FROM categorylinks 
JOIN page ON categorylinks.cl_from = page.page_id 
AND page.page_namespace = 0 
AND cl_to NOT LIKE '%Article%' 
AND cl_to NOT LIKE '%article%' 
AND cl_to NOT LIKE '%Wikipedia%' 
AND cl_to NOT LIKE '%redirect%' 
AND cl_to NOT LIKE '%page%' 
AND cl_to NOT LIKE '%Redirect%' 
AND page.page_title = "Ice_hockey";
```